# C++ Error LNK2019 ai::FilePath unresolved error symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, plugins

I'm actually stuck with this problem, I don't know why they said unresolved external symbol cause on Vstudio, ai::FilePath is recognized by the editor.

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol : "public: __cdecl ai::FilePath::FilePath(void)" (??0FilePath@ai@@QEAA@XZ)"

Someone can help me please, thank you !

Comment: Do you link with the library where that function is defined? (And no, including a header file isn't the same)

Comment: I actually include #include "IAIFilePath.cpp" and it's work but i don't know  .. it's strange to import a .cpp file ^^

Comment: Don't `#include` source files. Instead add the source file in the project structure and it should be built like any of your own source files, and linked into the executable.

Comment: How can I link the file? :/

Comment: Add the source-file to your Visual Studio project, and it will be built (and linked) like your own source-files.

Comment: You should show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the library file is not being found. IAIFilePath.cpp will most likely be built into a .lib file and that is what the linker is not finding.

Make sure you #include the header file, not the .cpp file also. While it can be done, its not the right thing to do.

Couple of options for you:

1. Copy the .lib file into the same directory as your program
2. Include the lib file as a linker input in the project properties
3. Point your linker directories to the folder which contains the .lib file for IAIFilePath.cpp